# Disable analyzer for dynamic fields

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elastic search index I have dynamic mapping enabled for a particular object, which means that any "string" fields that get added to this object are analyzed by default.

Is there a way to disable analysis for dynamic fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a 'dynamic template' that matches your string fields and applies a mapping that sets the field to 'not_analyzed'

see http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html

here's an example that makes the field available as both analyzed and un-analyzed

```
'dynamic_templates' : [
    {
     'string_template' : { 
       'match' : '*',
       'match_mapping_type' : 'string',
       'mapping' : { 
       'type'   : 'multi_field',
       'fields': { 
       '{name}' : {'type': 'string', 'index': 'analyzed', 'analyzer' : 'default'},
       'raw': { 'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'}" 
       }
     }
   }
 }
]
```

Comment: Note that this is illegal JSON - despite being based on Javascript object literal syntax, JSON requires strings to be double-quoted, not single-quoted.